# Filering received mail by aliases file ubuntu postfix mail server

Tags: server, postfix, mail, mailutils

I have setup an Ubuntu mail server with `/etc/aliases`.

In the aliases file there is an alias `all: group1, group2, group3`, where each of the groups is defined on its own.
The problem is that due to the importance and the number of people influenced by the alias `all@mydomain.com` anyone in possession of this email is able to send unwanted email. The server already has some kind of spam filter, I cannot recall which one.

*My question is is there a way to block all incoming mails to `all@mydomain.com` from any email not in `/etc/aliases`.*

I hope this post is not a duplicate. I have looked and found similar topics but none of them seemed to provide me with a solution to my question.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find more information from other sources such as [here](http://www.serveradminblog.com/2010/03/how-to-whitelist-hosts-or-ip-addresses-in-postfix/), [here](http://www.linuxlasse.net/linux/howtos/Blacklist_and_Whitelist_with_Postfix), and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/419807/how-to-configure-postfix-to-only-send-to-whitelisted-addresses).

Finally what I did was:

1) I wrote a script called update_postfix_white_list.bash

```
vi /etc/postfix/update_postfix_white_list.bash
```

2) Inside it I added:

```
#Parameters {aliases, white_list} file location.
aliasesfile="/etc/aliases"
postfixwhitelistfile="/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist"
# from aliases removed all the comments| removed all the names| found all the emails| sorted them and removed duplicates | added " OK" to each email > stored it to the "white_list" file
cut -d# ${aliasesfile} -f1 |  cut -d\: -f2| grep -EiEio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'| sort -u | sed -e 's/$/ OK/' > ${postfixwhitelistfile}
# Generated the hash file for the white list
postmap ${postfixwhitelistfile}
# Restarted the postfix server
service postfix restart
```

3) Then I modified the `main.cf` settings to take into consideration the "white_list" file.

```
vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

4) There I added:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist
    reject
```

5) As a final step I changed to executable the script and I ran it.

```
chmod u+x "/etc/postfix/update_postfix_white_list.bash"
/etc/postfix/update_postfix_white_list.bash
```

Which means to check using `check_sender_access` if the person who send the file is in the white/black list. Do not confuse it with `check_recipient_access`. The command `reject` will reject all the mails that were not accepted by the `check_sender_access`.

Note1: `check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist` has to be
after `reject_unauth_destination`, but before the first `blacklist` if you have them in your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` option, for more complex settings.

Note2: After the command `reject` nothing else will be checked.

Note3: If you desire you may use `crontab -e` and then to add `@daily /etc/postfix/update_postfix_white_list.bash` in order to have your server update daily your white-list automatically.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to improve this.